What is the correct and most economic way to type a function that is curried using ramda's curry?
Given a function:

const f = (a, b, c, d) => { – }

Which has these typings:
type F = (a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number): number

That is curried using Ramda's curry:
import { curry } from 'ramda'

const fc = curry(f)

How should fc be typed?
Given that there are four params, the function can be called in the following ways:
fc(1,1,1,1)
fc(1)(1)(1)(1)
fc(1)(1,1,1)
fc(1)(1,1)(1)
fc(1)(1)(1,1)
fc(1,1)(1)(1)
fc(1,1)(1,1)
fc(1,1,1)(1)

How can I efficiently provide typings without having to add each variation?
const fc: {
  (a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number): number,
  (a: number): (b: number): (c: number): (d: number) => number,
  (a: number): (b: number) =>  (c: number) =>  (d: number): number,
  …
} = curry(f)

If I curry a function an don't export it, I don't get any errors, however the moment I export a function I get the following error:
The inferred type of 'fc' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/ts-toolbelt@9.6.0/node_modules/ts-toolbelt/out/Function/Curry'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.



Doesn't ramda publish types? Why do you have to write anything?

@JaredSmith the error I get is The inferred type of 'fc' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/ts-toolbelt@9.6.0/node_modules/ts-toolbelt/out/Function/Curry'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary. I have @types/ramda installed.

You should probably include that info in the question if for no other reason to forestall "have you tried turning it on?" comments like the one I left earlier. So my understanding of TS2742 is that it only occurs when emitting declarations, are you working on a library or an app? If it's an app just don't emit declaration files.

@JaredSmith that was the problem. I'd copied over my tsconfig from a lib into an app. I set declaration: false and the error disappeared. Thanks for your help. If you want to write that up as an answer I will mark it. as correct, i.e. the error is caused by emiting declarations, and if you disable that you won't need to type the curried functions.

I've added info about the error to the question so your answer will make sense.

Error TS 2742 only occurs when the compiler is trying to emit type declarations. If you are working on application code (as opposed to library code) there is no need to emit declaration files as they are not used by either the browser or server JS runtimes like node.
Just set "declaration": false in your tsconfig.json.
